# Weird behavior of a function

Tags: c, function

In an exercise, I need to compare an array of `distances` and tell the shortest paths. For this, I need to read an input file with the cities' coordinates `(x,y)` and find all the possible routes and calculate the total distance of each route. This first part of the exercise I've already made it. I made the following function for printing all the possible routes:

```
void Troca(int *x, int *y)
{
    int aux;
    aux = *x;
    *x = *y;
    *y = aux;
}

void Permuta(FILE *saida, Cidade *C, int *sequencia, int inicio, int termino, int totalViagens, float **distanciasAux)
{
    int i, j;
    totalViagens = TotalViagens(termino);
    if(inicio == termino)
    {
        for(i = 0; i < termino; i++)
            fprintf(saida, "%d\t", sequencia[i]+1);
        fprintf(saida, "= %f\n", Distancia(C, termino, sequencia));

        *distanciasAux = (float *) malloc(totalViagens*sizeof(float));
        float *distancias = *distanciasAux;
        distancias[i] = Distancia(C, termino, sequencia);
        printf("\n%f\n", distancias[i]);
    }
    else
    {
        for(j = inicio; j < termino; j++)
        {
            Troca((sequencia+inicio), (sequencia+j));
            Permuta(saida, C, sequencia, inicio+1, termino, totalViagens, distanciasAux);
            Troca((sequencia+inicio), (sequencia+j));
        }
    }
}
```

I get the following result in an output file:

```
120
1   2   3   4   5   = 47.063416
1   2   3   5   4   = 61.486000
1   2   4   3   5   = 46.907471
1   2   4   5   3   = 62.644718
1   2   5   4   3   = 58.522675
1   2   5   3   4   = 57.208015
1   3   2   4   5   = 51.513924
1   3   2   5   4   = 61.814468
1   3   4   2   5   = 47.235947
1   3   4   5   2   = 58.522675
1   3   5   4   2   = 62.644718
1   3   5   2   4   = 61.658531
1   4   3   2   5   = 46.077225
1   4   3   5   2   = 57.208015
1   4   2   3   5   = 50.199272
1   4   2   5   3   = 61.658527
1   4   5   2   3   = 61.814472
1   4   5   3   2   = 61.485996
1   5   3   4   2   = 46.907475
1   5   3   2   4   = 50.199272
1   5   4   3   2   = 47.063412
1   5   4   2   3   = 51.513927
1   5   2   4   3   = 47.235943
1   5   2   3   4   = 46.077229
2   1   3   4   5   = 58.522675
2   1   3   5   4   = 62.644714
2   1   4   3   5   = 57.208019
2   1   4   5   3   = 61.486000
2   1   5   4   3   = 47.063416
2   1   5   3   4   = 46.907475
2   3   1   4   5   = 61.814472
2   3   1   5   4   = 51.513927
2   3   4   1   5   = 46.077225
2   3   4   5   1   = 47.063412
2   3   5   4   1   = 61.485996
2   3   5   1   4   = 50.199272
2   4   3   1   5   = 47.235947
2   4   3   5   1   = 46.907475
2   4   1   3   5   = 61.658527
2   4   1   5   3   = 50.199268
2   4   5   1   3   = 51.513927
2   4   5   3   1   = 62.644714
2   5   3   4   1   = 57.208015
2   5   3   1   4   = 61.658531
2   5   4   3   1   = 58.522675
2   5   4   1   3   = 61.814472
2   5   1   4   3   = 46.077225
2   5   1   3   4   = 47.235947
3   2   1   4   5   = 61.486000
3   2   1   5   4   = 47.063416
3   2   4   1   5   = 50.199272
3   2   4   5   1   = 51.513927
3   2   5   4   1   = 61.814472
3   2   5   1   4   = 46.077225
3   1   2   4   5   = 62.644714
3   1   2   5   4   = 58.522675
3   1   4   2   5   = 61.658531
3   1   4   5   2   = 61.814472
3   1   5   4   2   = 51.513927
3   1   5   2   4   = 47.235947
3   4   1   2   5   = 57.208015
3   4   1   5   2   = 46.077225
3   4   2   1   5   = 46.907471
3   4   2   5   1   = 47.235943
3   4   5   2   1   = 58.522675
3   4   5   1   2   = 47.063412
3   5   1   4   2   = 50.199272
3   5   1   2   4   = 46.907475
3   5   4   1   2   = 61.485996
3   5   4   2   1   = 62.644714
3   5   2   4   1   = 61.658531
3   5   2   1   4   = 57.208015
4   2   3   1   5   = 51.513927
4   2   3   5   1   = 50.199272
4   2   1   3   5   = 62.644714
4   2   1   5   3   = 46.907471
4   2   5   1   3   = 47.235943
4   2   5   3   1   = 61.658527
4   3   2   1   5   = 47.063416
4   3   2   5   1   = 46.077225
4   3   1   2   5   = 58.522675
4   3   1   5   2   = 47.235947
4   3   5   1   2   = 46.907475
4   3   5   2   1   = 57.208015
4   1   3   2   5   = 61.814468
4   1   3   5   2   = 61.658531
4   1   2   3   5   = 61.486000
4   1   2   5   3   = 57.208015
4   1   5   2   3   = 46.077225
4   1   5   3   2   = 50.199272
4   5   3   1   2   = 62.644714
4   5   3   2   1   = 61.485996
4   5   1   3   2   = 51.513927
4   5   1   2   3   = 47.063412
4   5   2   1   3   = 58.522675
4   5   2   3   1   = 61.814472
5   2   3   4   1   = 46.077225
5   2   3   1   4   = 61.814468
5   2   4   3   1   = 47.235947
5   2   4   1   3   = 61.658531
5   2   1   4   3   = 57.208015
5   2   1   3   4   = 58.522675
5   3   2   4   1   = 50.199272
5   3   2   1   4   = 61.486000
5   3   4   2   1   = 46.907471
5   3   4   1   2   = 57.208015
5   3   1   4   2   = 61.658531
5   3   1   2   4   = 62.644714
5   4   3   2   1   = 47.063416
5   4   3   1   2   = 58.522675
5   4   2   3   1   = 51.513924
5   4   2   1   3   = 62.644714
5   4   1   2   3   = 61.486000
5   4   1   3   2   = 61.814472
5   1   3   4   2   = 47.235943
5   1   3   2   4   = 51.513924
5   1   4   3   2   = 46.077225
5   1   4   2   3   = 50.199268
5   1   2   4   3   = 46.907471
5   1   2   3   4   = 47.063416
```

Where 120 represents the total possibilities (this is for five cities) and the lines below it shows each city's index+1 and at the end, the route's total distance.

In this function, I created an array `distancias`so I could store all total distances value. And I asked it to print on screen all the total distances of each route and it gives me the right values. But to compare these values, I need to make it in another function, because the function `Permuta` calls itself and I couldn't find a way to compare those values inside it. So I made this next function:

```
void CriaSequencia(FILE *saida, Cidade *C, int *sequencia, int numeroCidade, int totalViagens)
{
    int i;
    totalViagens = TotalViagens(numeroCidade);
    float *distancias;
    for(i = 0; i < numeroCidade; i++)
    {
        sequencia[i] = i;
    }
    Permuta(saida, C, sequencia, 0, numeroCidade, TotalViagens(numeroCidade), &distancias);
    for(i = 0; i < totalViagens; i++)
        printf("\n%f\n", distancias[i]);
}
```

I didn't compare them because I wanted to be sure if these values are the correct ones, but when I ask it to be printed, it doesn't give me the same value as the other functions gives me. It has a weird behavior like this:

```
47.063416
47.063416
47.063416
47.063416
47.063416
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
```

I would like to know why it doesn't print the correct values and what may be the problem in my functions.

Additional informatios:

City's struct:

```
typedef struct
{
    int x;
    int y;
} Cidade;
```

`Distancia` function:

```
float Distancia(Cidade *C, int numeroCidade, int *sequencia)
{
    int i;
    float total = 0;
    float distancia;
    for (i = 0; i < numeroCidade; i++)
    {
        /* distance from one city in the sequence to the next = ... ? */
        if(i == numeroCidade-1)
        {
            int distanciaX = pow(C[sequencia[i]].x - C[sequencia[0]].x, 2);
            int distanciaY = pow(C[sequencia[i]].y - C[sequencia[0]].y, 2);
            distancia = sqrt(distanciaX + distanciaY);
            total = total + distancia;
        }
        else
        {
            int distanciaX = pow(C[sequencia[i]].x - C[sequencia[i+1]].x, 2);
            int distanciaY = pow(C[sequencia[i]].y - C[sequencia[i+1]].y, 2);
            distancia = sqrt(distanciaX + distanciaY);
            total = total + distancia;
        }
    }
    return total;
}
```

`TotalViagens` function

```
int TotalViagens(int numeroCidade)
{
    int i;
    int total = 1;
    for(i = 1; i <= numeroCidade; i++)
        total = total*i;
    return total;
}
```

Comment: you don't allocate any memory for `distancias` so of course it's going to print out random values

Comment: I tried to make it in the function `Permuta`. Is it wrong? How should I make it?

Comment: No, i was wrong - you are allocating memory, but you keep allocating a new chunk each time you calculate a distance losing the previous results. And I'm not sure you're storing the value in the right part of the allocated chunk either

Comment: But why does it print null values? Or why does it print the first `distancias` value five times and then it starts printing null values? Is there any idea?

Comment: It would be clearer if you used the English words in the code.

Comment: what/where is the definition of the type: `Cidade`?

Comment: The posted code is missing the needed `#include` statements for `stdio.h` < FILE, printf(), fprintf() >  `stdlib.h` <malloc())  What about `free()`>

Comment: please post a [mcve] so we can run/debug your code.

Comment: in function: ``  this line: `totalViagens = TotalViagens(numeroCidade);` does not set the callers' variable.  To set the callers' variable, the parameters `totalViagens` must be passed as a pointer to the variable.  Note: function: `TotalViagens()` not found anywhere in the posted code.

Comment: I'll edit the question with more informativo
Note: `TotalViagens` funcionários calculates the total number of possibilities, returning an `int`

Comment: the definition of the function: `Distancia()` is missing, not even a prototype in the posted code

Comment: when calling any of the heap allocation functions: (malloc, calloc, realloc) 1) always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  2) the returned type is `void*` which can be assigned to any pointer.  Casting just clutters the code, making it more difficult to understand, debug, etc  3) the function malloc() is called many times, but the resulting memory is never passed to `free()`.  This results in a massive memory leak.

Comment: the function: `Permuta()` is recursive.  What is the max number of recursions?  From the posted code, this max recursions number looks to be very large.

Comment: Yes. The function `Permuta`, for a high number of cities, is very large. For this example, with 5 cities,the number of possibilites is 5! = 120. For 14 cities, it passes 80 billions, I guess. But I think the exercise's intention is to check how long does the program take to calculate all of these possibilites and tell the shortest routes.

Comment: Since each city is given a set of coordinates (x,y)  1) I would expect the code to be using those coordinates.  2) I would expect some calculations using the (x,y) for two different cities to calculate the distance between those cities.  3) I would expect a struct definition that contains the fields (x,y) 4) I would expect any array of such struct instances.  I'm not seeing any of those details of data in the posted code.

Comment: At `Distancia` function I do use the struct `Cidade` and its coordinates `(x,y)`. At this part of the code I didn't use too much of the struct because I thought it wasn't needed. I was trying to use their Index.

Comment: You're calling `TotalViagens` way too often - you pass in into `Permuta` so why do you calculate it again at the beginning of the function? You only need to call it once ever in your program when you know how many cities you have.